# jQuery ajax problem with IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-6

Hi my problem is a bit wired:

my $.ajax success handler looks like:

```
function(data){
        alert(data);
}
```

Pretty simple, yeah?

The problem is that data IS ALWAYS 3 character long - no matter what was sent by the server! The characters: 31 65535 8 (using charCodeAt()).

In other browsers (even in IE 8) all works fine.

I've looked at xhr.responseText in complete handler - just the same result.

**UPDATE**
Full http response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2010 13:35:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4
Set-Cookie: 1111111111111111=UjVXb1Q3WTdUIQ8jXmALbA88VzpRcVcgBzMDcldyUmtWawAyAFpQP1IwASEAbFh%2FDjoLZ1RiBWlWdwBnUGMHZlU2UGBTZFA5B2UMMlJgC29SbVdjVDRZOVRsDzReaQtuDzpXZVFjV2UHYwM1VzNSNlYzAG4AMVAwUjUBIQBsWH8OOgtlVGAFaVZ3AD5QIgdcVWVQNlNhUHIHMAwjUiQLL1JvVyZUOVk8VGkPal54C2wPNVcyUX1XYgdgAzlXL1IzVioAbQA3UG9SdgE4ACRYNg4xC2RUagVxViAAJFA3B3FVW1AzU2JQZQc7DCRSdQs2UidXb1Q2WT1UYA9yXhcLMg92V2lRP1c%2FBzcDLlc1UixWNAB8AC1QNVI7AW4AJ1htDnQLPVQyBT9WMABsUHIHTlVXUBtTQFAgB20MflJnCzZSdFcCVGpZY1Q%2BDz9eLQsuDyxXTlEHV3MHYAMvVzBSOVYmAGcAdlBsUmUBMABtWC4ObAs1VCMFJ1YKADZQMQd3VW1QJFNsUHQHLAxyUmwLflJuV2RUM1k3VHgPYV5oC2sPOVc1UWdXagdgAzBXOVIgVj8AIQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 07-Feb-2012 13:35:39 GMT; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 21
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

1
```

**UPDATE !**
Well, problem temporary? solved by disabling gzip in .htaccess

Comment: In that HTTP response these headers are wrong
 Content-Length: 21 and Content-Encoding: gzip
What happens when they match the content?

Answer (score 0):

The characters you get look weird, but could it be that it's a [**BOM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)? It's none of the ones listed in the article, but maybe getCharCode() gets something wrong.

In that case, you would have to check the script you call to request the data. Try saving it explicitly without a BOM.

Comment: server-side script it's just echo "1";

Comment: @Trickster Well, have you checked for a BOM? It's an invisible mark in the beginning of the file.

Comment: What happens if you add a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header? Have you checked the encoding of your file?

Comment: Have you checked out the BOM issue?

Answer (score 0):

this is most times an problem with propper encoding of the requested content / displayed content.

Please verify that both use the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Despite ajax is always done in UTF-8 some implementations are weird and they don't allow passing non ascii characters. You have to change them to entities.

If You pass only one character and still get problems - It might be the BOM mentioned by Pekka. You would have to save Your PHP FILE without any spaces before

Second thing is that You might be outputing something at the end of the php file.